# To make motion estimation step spatial homogeneity

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

we want to make algorithms

```
(average) Md=1/(N^2-K) ∑||(x,y)-S(x,y)||
```

where N is the size of the block, S(x, y) is the location
of the selected pixel nearest to the pixel at location (x, y)
and K is the number of selected pixels. Lower the value
of μd and σ2 d, the more is the spatial homogeneity of the
sampling lattice.

For `K=9`
I write a matlab code for this algorithm. I didn't find what's wrong with code

```
for i=2:1:a-1  
    for j=2:1:b-1
        S=blok(i-1:i+1;j-1:j+1);
        sum=sum+abs(blok(i,j)-S(i,j));
    end 
end
Md =double(sum/((a*b)-9));
```

Comment: 1. What is `blok`? 2. What is `a` and `b`? 3. **Never** use `sum` as a variable name. It is a built-in function, and overwriting it will only cause bugs.  4. What exactly doesn't work? Any error messages? 5. Can you give sample input variables and what you want the function to return for those values?

Comment: input is block 16x16 .block=16x16 (piece of image) axb=16x16  thanks for advice @Robert P.

Comment: Take a look at `blockproc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input is block 16x16
block=16x16  (piece of image)

i found S(x,y) making kernel[1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1] convolution with block

```
for i=1:1:14
  for j=1:1:14

    for m=-1:1
        for n=-1:1
            S(i+1,j+1)=S(i+1,j+1)+kernel(m+2,n+2).*blok(i-m+1,j-m+1);
        end
    end
   % S=blok(i-1:i+1;j-1:j+1);

    total=total+abs(blok(i+1,j+1)-S(i+1,j+1));


   end 
 end
```

its seems work for now but ı am not sure.